Using authblk \author in a tex cls file with a \foreach loop
I wrote a cls file containing:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Bug}[2024/07/12 Bug]
\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside,openbib]{article}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{myConf}{%
  store authors       = \myConf@authors,
  store organisations = \myConf@organisations,
  store title         = \myConf@title
}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{myConf}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{authblk}

\title{\myConf@title}

\newcounter{authorIndex}
\setcounter{authorIndex}{0}
\foreach \g in \myConf@authors {
  \stepcounter{authorIndex}
  \foreach \a in \g {
    \author[\the\value{authorIndex}]{\a}
  }
}

\newcounter{affIndex}
\setcounter{affIndex}{0}
\foreach \a in \myConf@organisations {
  \stepcounter{affIndex}
  \affil[\theaffIndex]{\a}
}

\renewcommand\Authsep{, }
\renewcommand\Authand{, }
\renewcommand\Authands{, }

And a latex document like :
\documentclass[
authors={{auth 1.1, auth 1.2},{auth 2.1},{auth 3.1}},
organisations={org 1, org 2, org 3},
title={Some title}
]{Bug}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
a lot of text
\end{document}

I expect the authors list to be separated by a comma but I get this:

Can anyone tell me why ?
Jouke
PS. I tried to post this a couple of hours ago but I can't find that post so I wrote it again. Sorry if this is doubled.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78740943/2777074
